# Symfony 5 - Download files uploaded with vich

Tags: symfony

After add functionnality upload file or many files thanks the bundle "vich", i would download the file who uploaded. My files are saved into a upload folder created to the root folder.

I've this code but error saying "file not found"..

```
<a download class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{'upload/' ~ document.image }}"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i> {{ document.image }} </a>
```

Comment: and with "root folder" you mean ... the symfony root where src and config etc. is located? because from the outside only directories in `public/` are accessible easily, everything else has to be delivered by a controller. so I would suggest you move your upload directory into the public directory. if you want to add access control though, you should build a controller that delivers the file.

Comment: yes exactly. So i have to create a new function on the controller for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download a file when you use Vich uploader bundle, you have to create a function inside your controller class and call it from your template.

For example:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Handler\DownloadHandler;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(...)
     *
     * @param Document        $document        The document to download
     * @param DownloadHandler $downloadHandler Handler
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function downloadDocument(Document $document, DownloadHandler $downloadHandler): Response
    {
        return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($document, 'documentFile');
    }
}
```

Form more information, see [VichUploaderBundle serving_files_with_a_controller](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/downloads/serving_files_with_a_controller.md)

Comment: the route in OP's case is probably `/upload/{filepath}`